# Create column translation table for two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, one of which has around 300 columns, the other has around 30.

The 30 columns in the second dataframe all come from the first but all have different column names.

How can I run analysis of those 30 columns on the first table to show which columns they most likely represent?

Is there a way to do this using Pandas?

Example data:

```
sample_dict_1 = {
    'col_1': [1,2,3,4,5],
    'col_2': [6,7,8,9,10],
    'col_3': [11,12,13,14,15],
    'col_4': [16,17,18,19,20],
    'col_4': [21,22,23,24,25]
}

sample_dict_2 = {
    'col_a': [11,12,13,14,15],
    'col_b': [6,7,8,9,10],
    'col_c': [21,22,23,24,28]
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(sample_dict_1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(sample_dict_2)
```

[image]

[image]

As you can see from the data above col_a and col_b match col_3 and col_2.

col_c partially matches col_4.

I would like to produce an output that gives me the percentage matches of the tables, something like:

```
col_a
col_3 100%
col_1 0%
...

col_c
col_4 80%
col_1 0%
...
```

Comment: Can you explain this with some sample data and expected output?

Comment: added some dummy data and an example of what I'd like

Comment: Do each of these dataframes have the same number of rows?

Comment: no they don't, theres  quite a large difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very pythonic but this will get you through.  You can collet the results if you need a dataframe...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
sample_dict_1 = {
    'col_1': [1,2,3,4,5],
    'col_2': [6,7,8,9,10],
    'col_3': [11,12,13,14,15],
    'col_4': [16,17,18,19,20],
    'col_4': [21,22,23,24,25]
}

sample_dict_2 = {
    'col_a': [11,12,13,14,15],
    'col_b': [6,7,8,9,10],
    'col_c': [21,22,23,24,28]
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(sample_dict_1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(sample_dict_2)

lista = df1.columns
listb = df2.columns

for a in lista:
    for b in listb:
        count = np.where(df1[a] == df2[b], 1, 0)
        perc = 100 * count.sum() / count.size

        print("match between "+a+" and "+b+" is "+str(perc))
```

and if they don't have the same number of rows then you need to change the matching from == to isin()